# How to hide child view from parent view after some delay

Tags: ios, swift, timer, parentviewcontroller

hide child view after few seconds 
I set time for that but i cant access child viewcontroller in my timer function
I tried dissmiss , removefromparent about not worked.
only `self.view.isHidden = true` is worked
I can't place it in timer

My Parent view

[image]

Child View:

[image]

Button code:
[image]

Timer code:[image]

Comment: Do not paste the images of code, rather add the code in question.

Comment: If you want the view controller to dismiss itself use `self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: `dismiss` function only works when you'r segue type is `Present Modally`

Comment: @Ankit Jayaswal you are right.

Comment: @Kazi dismiss is not worked in  this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Like_btn_Action()` function, you:

- create an instance of `LikeViewController`
- add it as a child view controller
- add its view to your view
- set that view's background color

and then the function exits. At this point, you no longer have a reference to your instance of `LikeViewController` ... `likeVC` has gone out of scope.

You need to use a class-level var to maintain the reference to the loaded child view controller, along these lines:

```
var likeVC: LikeViewController?
@IBAction func Like_btn_Action(_ sender: Any) {
    likeVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController( etc ...)
}
```

Then, when you want to remove the view you added, you can "get to it" via:

```
likeVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
```

for example.